# window.addEventListener for localStorage won't fire onClick

Tags: reactjs

I want to capture a change in `localStorage` using `window.addEventListener('storage')` using code below.

```
class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.storageChanged = this.storageChanged.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('storage', this.storageChanged);
  }
  storageChanged(e) { 
    alert('storageChanged');
    console.log(e);
  }
  render() { ... }
}
```

This works perfect by manually changing localStorage from Inspect > Application > Local Storage.

But following does not work when I try to change localStorage using `onClick`

```
class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.storageChanged = this.storageChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('storage', this.storageChanged);
  }
  storageChanged(e) { 
    alert('storageChanged');
    console.log(e);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','false');
  }
  render() { 
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

So when I click the button, `isLoggedIn` changes, but `storageChanged` won't fire. What could be wrong?

Comment: try adding window.addEventListener('storage', this.storageChanged) in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent):

> The StorageEvent is fired whenever a change is made to the Storage object (note that this event is not fired for sessionStorage changes). **This won't work on the same page that is making the changes** — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made.

So, everything is working as expected, but you can use `storage` event this way only if change is made on a different page (like manually changing it using the devtools menu)

You can trigger the event manually after each change if you like

```
  handleClick(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','false');
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'));
  }
```

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent` won't work because I won't get `event.newValue` and `event.key`. For now, I will give up hooking up to `localStoarge` for change events and instead use Redux Store. I'll only write to `localStorage` within Redux Actions, and get `localStorage` items within Redux Reducers only.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
handleClick(e) {
  const eventMock = {}; // my event mock if needed
  localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','false');
  storageChanged(eventMock);
}
```